# Why is my Django form for user sign up not “valid”? ValidationError 'This field is required.'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to write a signup form in Django, but I keep getting a Validation error when I post

> 'date_joined': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])

The form is based on the django user model. I have not got this field on the form because it's value can be set in code

**html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'sign-up' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Bid for Game - Sign Up</h1>
    Your first and last names will be used to help your friends identify you on the site.
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ signup_form.first_name.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ signup_form.first_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ signup_form.last_name.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ signup_form.last_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ signup_form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ signup_form.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ signup_form.email.label_tag }}</td>
            <td class='email'>{{ signup_form.email }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ signup_form.password.label_tag }}</td>
            <td><class='password'>{{ signup_form.password }}</class></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm password: </td>
            <td class='password'>{{ signup_form.confirm_password }}</class</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', max_length=30)
    username = forms.CharField(label='User name', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'email'}))
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    confirm_password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    date_joined = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'password_repeat': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    @staticmethod
    def initialise(request):
        """Return a dict of initial values."""
        initial = {
            'first_name': request.POST['first_name'],
            'last_name': request.POST['last_name'],
            'username': request.POST['username'],
            'email': request.POST['email'],
            'date_joined': datetime.datetime.today()
        }
        return initial
```

**views.py**

```
class SignUp(View):
    url = "users/signup.html"
    form_context = {
        'signup_form': SignupForm,
    }

    def get(self, request):
        context = self.form_context
        return render(request, self.url, context)

    def post(self, request):
        signup_form = SignupForm()
        signup_form.initial = SignupForm.initialise(request)
        context = {'signup_form': signup_form}
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('valid')
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())
            print('invalid')
```

As date_joined is a required field, where do I set it?

Comment: Why do you use a model form and then override all fields for no good reason?

Comment: @Melvyn Didn't realise I didn't need to. doesn't make any difference if I comment out the form model fields

Comment: Then date_joined is the standard date_joined from the User model. You need to remove that from the fields, but you've set fields to `"__all__"`. You probably can get away with `exclude = ('date_joined',)` instead of `fields = "__all__"`. And then you only need to provide custom fields for password and confirm password. The rest will be setup correctly based on the model fields.

Comment: That's it. Please put in an answer that I can accept

Comment: You are getting this error because you sets the value of date_joined after the server has received the data via POST request, but normally you would set the value for date_joined in your model and don't show it to the user, as it wouldn't be necessary for him to set it differently. You would need only the model and the class view that shows the model as a form. No need to create a SignupForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a lot of times, I see people use things and then override everything that thing does for them for free. The form and view above can be reduced to something akin to this (untested, but it's a good enough start):

```py
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("date_joined",)


from django.views.generic import CreateView
class SignupView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignupForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        password = data.pop('password')
        confirm_password = data.pop('confirm_password')
        if password != confirm_password:
            form.add_error('Passwords do not match')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        user = User.objects.create_user(**data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
```